# KendoUI mvc grid with dropdown throwing error on new record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, drag-and-drop, kendo-grid

When i click new record, i get the following error.

Here is the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Application is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (kendo.all.js:194), <anonymous>:3:651)
    at init._rowsHtml (kendo.all.js:60907)
    at init._renderContent (kendo.all.js:61573)
    at init.refresh (kendo.all.js:61411)
    at init.d (jquery.min.js:2)
    at init.trigger (kendo.all.js:124)
    at init._process (kendo.all.js:7327)
    at init._change (kendo.all.js:7287)
    at init.d (jquery.min.js:2)
    at init.trigger (kendo.all.js:124)
```

[image: this is what i get]

here is my code:

`columns.Bound(c => c.Application).ClientTemplate("#=Application.Name#").EditorTemplateName("ApplicationDropDownEditor");`

Here is the editor:

```
@model Configuration.Web.Models.ApplicationViewModel
@(
            Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("Type")
            .DataTextField("Name")
            .DataValueField("Id")
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("GetApplications", "Application");
                }
            );
            })
)
```

My Class:

```
public class ConfigViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [UIHint("ApplicationDropDownEditor")]
    public ApplicationViewModel Application { set; get; }
    public EnvironmentViewModel Environment { set; get; }

    public int? ApplicationId { set; get; }
    public int? EnvironmentId { set; get; }
}
```

Why am i getting this error?

Comment: if it happens everytime you click on Add Row, then its because Application isn't defined so when it tries to find Application.name, its trying to find name of null, which is why you're getting the error

Comment: Yes I know that. but wouldnt it find it?

Comment: Even when I `ClientTemplate("#=Application ? 'test':'this'#")` still doesnt work. Grid doesnt know about that class.

Comment: can you load the grid( without Application in the template ) and just put it as a value in a hidden input to see if a value exists? so when you try to add a row, it will add a value into the input to see if application actually has a value

Comment: What is the relation between ApplicationViewModel
 and ConfigViewModel ? Is the Editor using the correct view model ?

Comment: ConfigViewModel has AppplicationViewModel. Editor is supposed to use ApplicationViewModel. not sure if it is using the correct one or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding:

```
      .Model(model =>
      {
          model.Id(p => p.Id);
          model.Field(field => field.App).DefaultValue(new ApplicationViewModel());
      })
```

Did the job.